# angular-google-maps : google is not defined

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, maps

I see from these [threads](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1853) that there is an error with v2.3.3.

But even after downgrading to 2.3.2, its not working, keeps giving me "google is not defined", wherever I am trying to use google object. Please check this plunker - 
http://plnkr.co/edit/AJpJxBHF1SpwCtRKEzPF?p=preview
(This is infact the same code given in [angular-google-maps documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/drawing-manager), except for the change in the library version)

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-maps/2.3.1/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
```

I have changed the angular-google-maps to v2.3.2.

Please let me know if you are able to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: Did you include the google maps API script? You need to include it either as another script import or by using the [provider](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/GoogleMapApi).

Comment: Thanks, yes I included the google maps API script and it worked. But I was expecting that the component itself would take care of this. 

Thanks.